# CSS spin button cross browser, work for Chrome but not for firefox/safari

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have this spin up/down button works perfectly in Google Chrome(mac os), but when I open it with Safari it is a little off the grid, and in Firefox it is completely disappeared.

Could anyone help with the CSS? Thanks for any help

> Chrome (CSS working really well):

[image]

> Safari (kind off from the input field):

[image]

> Firefox (not showing at all?):

[image]

```css
/* style input number spinner */

input[type="number"] {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
}


/* Spin Buttons modified */

input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #FFF url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJCAYAAADgkQYQAAAAKUlEQVQYlWNgwAT/sYhhKPiPT+F/LJgEsHv37v+EMGkmkuImoh2NoQAANlcun/q4OoYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) no-repeat center center;
  width: 1em;
  border-left: 1px solid #BBB;
  opacity: 0.7;
  /* shows Spin Buttons per default (Chrome >= 39) */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button:hover,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #0CF;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <td><input type="number" min="0.001" step="0.001" name="price" value="" required=""></td>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per , [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-inner-spin-button) This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

[image]

Still you can do something like this for FireFox (this won't work for chrome):

```css
div:before, div:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    height: 8px;
    line-height: 8px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    left: 136px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
}

div:before {
    content: "▲ ";
    top: 11px;
}

div:after {
    content: "▼";
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="number" value="55" min="0" max="100" step="5" /></div>
```

Hope this helps!